# Одновременная проверка нескольких элементов массива по диапазону

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Необходимо ОДНОВРЕМЕННО проверить три элемента(второй, третий, четвертый) массива на соответствие диапазонам

```
if array[1] < 1 || array[2] < 1 || array[3] < 1 {
   print("хотя бы один из элементов меньше 1")
} else if  array[1] == 1...10 || array[2] == 1...10 || array[3] == 1...10 { // ЭТА ЗАПИСЬ НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНАЯ!!!!!! КАК СОСТАВИТЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО????????
   print("элементы от одного до десетяти")
} else {
   print("элементы больше десяти")
}
```

Не могу сообразить, через switch получается только проверять по одному элементу массива по отдельности, но нужно сразу три одновременно

Необходимые условия:

1- если хотя бы один из элементов (второй, третий, четвертый) или все три меньше единицы, то...

2 -если хотя бы два элемента(втророй, третий либо четвертый) в диапазоне от 1 до 10, а оставшийся один больше десяти, либо все в диапазоне от 1 до 10, то...

3 - если хотя бы два элемента(втророй, третий либо четвертый) в диапазоне больше 10, а оставшийся один в диапазоне от 1 до 10, либо все в диапазоне больше 10, то...

Comment: `если то..` а у вас `если - иначе если`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя так писать в if. Необходимо использовать:

```
if 1...10 ~= yourNum {}
```

Если непонятно как составить условие, распишите максимально подробно для себя чтоб понять это условие. Есть пара чисел в диапазоне 1...10, а третье > 10, то возможно 3 виарианта:

1 за диапазоном, 2 и 3 в. или

2 за диапазоном, 1 и 3 в. или

3 за диапазоном, 2 и 1 в.

Учитывая первое условие можно просто проверять на <= 10 и > 10:

1 больше 10, 2 и 3 меньше. или

2 больше 10, 1 и 3 меньше. или

3 больше 10, 2 и 1 меньше.